# what methodology encryption drupal has used for username and password authentication and validation

Tags: drupal

Drupal site migrated into PHP Framework,

In new database and current drupal contents are migrated,

Show stopper ? is login authentication.

what methodology / encryption method drupal has used for username and password authentication and validation.

Comment: It's all in here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/7

Comment: @Clive guide me if i am wrong, the reference u added is for drupal hook. but i am looking through PHP Code i want to perform the authentication.  exactly am looking what is the PHP CODE will perform the authtication

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean - there are no hooks in that file, it's an include file not a module. Those are the methods that core Drupal uses to hash passwords; if you want to reproduce that in custom code, password.inc contains everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal code is open source and, in the case of user authentication, quite easy to understand. One only have to look at the source (Clive already provided the link on the comment to the OP).

With Drupal core, user authentication is password based. User authentication is done in the [`user_authenticate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_authenticate/7) function. Actual password verification is done in the [`user_check_password()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_check_password/7) function. As one can see, this actually compare hashed passwords (the stored one, and the one provided as clear-text to the function). Password hashes are computed using the [`_password_crypt()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/_password_crypt/7) function, using salt and repeated hashing to increase security.

If you need to re-use Drupal user authentication outside of Drupal but keeping the password unchanged, you will need to replicate the `user_check_password()` function and all it dependencies.